# Router, model, or view, which one is the initiator

Tags: rest, backbone.js, creation

I am trying to be as lazy loading as possible,

But, I am puzzle on how to start, here is my "sequenced comprehension":

Objective: Create a contacts page with contacts existing on the server

- Step1.0: To use the router: the `<div id="contacts">` must exists to trigger a rule, so I stepped back to (Step0.9),
- Step0.9: Created this div in the body.  Fine, the router find the #contacts, Oh, but this is a view, ok, stepped back to (Step0.8).
- Step0.8: Erase the div created in the `body` and replace it by a view instead:

> ```
> contactsView = Backbone.View.extend 
> tagName: 'div',
> id: 'contacts'
> ```

To be lazy loading, this view should only be created when the #contact is trigger in my router table, but I just removed it from by body, it does exist anymore, I am back to Step1.0 ???

Some tutorials found, shows global variable settings... Please, how the general scenario using a router, a view, their models, and collection should proceed (no code is necessary for an answer, just one line for each steps) ?

I know there can be multiples ways, but what is the most common backbone step strategy to create elements.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm not 100% sure I understood you correctly. If I didn't please let me know in the comments.*

There seems to be some confusion in your question regarding the usage of `Backbone.Router` in general. When the router maps a route to URL fragment `#contacts`, that has nothing to do with a DOM element with the id `#contacts`. The hash sign simply happens to be the identifier for an URL fragment **and** `id` CSS selector, but that's where the similarity ends.

Typically my router looks something like this:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    contacts: "contactList"
  },
  contactList: function() {
    var contacts = new ContactCollection();
    var view = new ContactListView({collection:contacts});
    view.render().$el.appendTo("#contacts");
  }
});
```

Notice that the `#contacts` element doesn't need to  be called that. You can call it `#pony`, or you can render the view directly to the document `body` if you want.

So in these terms the workflow is:

1. Router gets hit
2. Collection is initialized
3. View is rendered

Comment: Perfect answer, you pin point my confusion, thanks, regards. I cannot upvote your answer, but I will.

Answer (score 1):

Usual way i do is

- Have the `div#contacts` loaded within body
- Router maps the `#contacts` to the method `showContacts` in the router
- showContacts creates the view, attaches it to the desired div

  `var view = new contactsView();`

  `$('#contacts').empty().append(view.el);`

  `view.render();`
- You need not define the id in the definition of `contactsView`

Comment: Thanks, 'fencliff' identified my confusion, regards.